# ask : error to show Jtable from database with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i've run my main method

```
package com.dascom.view;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new JFrameDatabarang().setVisible(true);

        }

    }
```

and get error

```
        Connection succes
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dascom.controller.DatabarangController.isiTable(DatabarangController.java:54)
            at com.dascom.view.JFrameDatabarang.<init>(JFrameDatabarang.java:130)
            at com.dascom.view.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

this is at DatabarangController.java:54

```
frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().setModel(dtm);
```

on my DatabarangConroller class

```
public class DatabarangController {


        JFrameDatabarang frameDatabarang;
        Databarangimpl databarangimpl;
        List<Databarang> listDatabarang;


    public DatabarangController(JFrameDatabarang frameDatabarang)  {
    this.frameDatabarang = frameDatabarang;
    databarangimpl = new DatabarangDAO();
    listDatabarang = databarangimpl.getByAll();

    }


    public void isiTable() {
            listDatabarang = databarangimpl.getByAll();
            DatabarangTabelModel dtm = new DatabarangTabelModel(listDatabarang);
            frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().setModel(dtm);

        }
    }
```

this is JFrameDatabarang.java:130

```
databarangController.isiTable();
```

in

```
    public JFrameDatabarang() {
    initcomponent();

    databarangController = new DatabarangController(this);
    databarangController.isiTable();

    JtableDatabarang = new JTable();
    JtableDatabarang.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            databarangController.isiField(JtableDatabarang.getSelectedRow());


        }
    });
    JtableDatabarang.setBounds(17, 384, 599, 136);
    contentPane.add(JtableDatabarang);

    }
```

@Katja
i put jtableDatabarang include in public JframeDatabarang()

so. after i put recomend as @katja and @Denish.

the JFrameDatabarang is run. and i try to put a value in JFrameDatabarang.

i got error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at com.dascom.controller.DatabarangController.insert(DatabarangController.java:74)
at com.dascom.view.JFrameDatabarang$3.actionPerformed(JFrameDatabarang.java:235)
```

this is DatabarangController.java:74

```
databarang.setHargajual(Double.parseDouble(frameDatabarang.JtextHargajual().getText()));
```

on DatabarangController class i make a method insert

```
public void insert()   {
    Databarang databarang = new Databarang();

    databarang.setNamabarang(frameDatabarang.JtextNamabarang().getText());
    databarang.setStok(Integer.parseInt(frameDatabarang.JtextStok().getText()));
    databarang.setHargajual(Double.parseDouble(frameDatabarang.JtextHargajual().getText()));
    databarang.setHargabeli(Double.parseDouble(frameDatabarang.JtextHargabeli().getText()));
    databarang.setSatuanukuran(frameDatabarang.JtextSatuanukuran().getText());
    databarang.setDeksripsi(frameDatabarang.JtextDeskripsi().getText());
    databarang.setKeterangan(frameDatabarang.JtextKeterangan().getText());

    databarangimpl.insertDatabarang(databarang);
}
```

i try to search a topic in same error with me in stackoverflow on

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

nothing get the solution.

Comment: Could be because you pass `this` to a method in the constructor of `JFrameDatabarang`, causing `isiTable` to use the object before it is fully constructed.

Comment: I guess the method JtableDatabarang() returns null. Can you provide the sourcecode for this method?

Comment: if i put null at DatabarangController its not call a value from
    frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().seModel(dtm);

Comment: @DenisLukenich which method you asking. may you explain please

Comment: In this line: `frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().setModel(dtm);` You call the Method `JtableDatabarang()`. I guess this method returns null. So i ask for that sourcecode.

Comment: i put on public JTable JtableDatabarang.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code of JtableDatabarang. It's important to see what it returns.

Comment: Comment for your edit: The variable `JFrameDatabarangyou` initialized in the Constructor. This is fine. However the call you do `JFrameDatabarang()` indicates that there is a method with this name.

Comment: @DenisLukenich either that or it's a typo. When the line meant to read `frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang.setModel(dtm);` it is working on a not yet initialized object.

Comment: @daunjeruk can you confirm that JtableDatabarang() was a typo? If it is, I have an answer for you.

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen did i missing something?
DenisLukenich what method in the name...

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen no JtableDatabrang() was build Constructor from public JTable JtableDatabarang

Comment: You showed that JtableDatabarang is on object of the type JTable. To reference it, you could write `frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang.setModel(dtm);`. You use `frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().setModel(dtm);` instead. The brackets indicate a _method call_ instead of a referenced object, so the question is: do you have a method with that name defined in JFrameDatabarang?

Comment: i declare in 
'JframeDatabarang extend Jframe { 
private JTable JtableDatabarang;
 public JTable JtableDatabarang() {
 return JtableDatabarang;
}"

Comment: Ah ok, that is your getter. A small tip for the future: things like these are more easy to understand if you use the naming conventions of Java, in this case calling the object jTableDatabarang and the getter getJTableDatabarang. Less confusing! Adding my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens while constructing `JFrameDatabarang`:

1. In the constructor of `JFrameDatabarang` you pass a reference to `this` to the constructor of `databarangController`.
2. You call the method `isiTable` on the controller.
3. `isiTable` tries to execute `frameDatabarang.JtableDatabarang().setModel(dtm);` and fails (`JtableDatabarang()` being the getter, as confirmed in the comments). The exception is thrown before the program could reach the creation of the `JtableDatabarang` object in `JFrameDatabarang`.

It is best to avoid passing `this` out of a constructor because working with a not fully constructed object could lead to hard to find errors.

At least make sure that everything (like `JtableDatabarang`) is created before you use it.

Comment: katja can u specify more.  i hard to understand in point 3.

how to avoid passing 'databarangController = new DatabarangController(this);
  databarangController.isiTable();

'

Comment: See the answer of @DenisLukenich: The sequence matters. Take care to properly initialize everything you are going to use. Use a debugger to step thru the programm to check method calls and variable content if you are unsure. To avoid using not fully constructed objects, do only the necessary things in the constructor (like variable initialization).

Comment: its show the frame , but error to show a value or input a value form database to JtableDatabarang.

Answer (score 1):

As Katja indicated, your order is wrong, so change:

```
databarangController = new DatabarangController(this);
databarangController.isiTable();

JtableDatabarang = new JTable();
```

to:

```
JtableDatabarang = new JTable();
databarangController = new DatabarangController(this);
databarangController.isiTable();
```